# Styling a image in js without the img tag

Tags: javascript, image, styling

I mean something like this :

```
document.getElementById("image-div").innerHTML="<img src=''>";
```

How we can change the width/height of the image in js? I tried but nothing.
Is changing the id(container) but the image size still the same.

Comment: An image does not contain HTML :/ Share the code please

Comment: _I tried but nothing_. Please show how you tried to change the width and height

Comment: Thanks your for your answer . So the only way to change the size is by adding a img tag in html and after resize it with js right ?  Because i am begginer and i wanted to see if is some other way . I don't have any code i just wanted to know if i can edit a js image from js and not to have it in html . Just curiosity.

Comment: var trying= document.getElementById('image-div');
trying.style.height = "150px";
trying.style.width = "150px";                                                                                                     
or  ,,,,                                                                                                   document.getElementById("image-div").style.height = "250px";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed your using innerHTML to add an image as opposed to the image already existing. There are a number of ways to achieve what you're asking. I haven't tested any of this but I figured I'd try to help you find a solution.

1. `.innerHTML('<img src="src" style="height:10px; width: 10px;">')` as you have demonstrated. This should make add an image with the selected INLINE styling.
2. This solution adds inline styling to a image element created through javascript.

   `let div = document.getElementById("image-div")`

   `let img = document.createElement('img');`

   `img.src = 'https://extremelycoolimage.com/image.png';`

   `img.style.width = '100px';`

   `img.style.height = '100px';`

   `div.appendChild(img);`
3. This solution adds class styling to a image element created through javascript.

   `let div = document.getElementById("image-div")`

   `let img = document.createElement('img');`

   `img.src = 'https://extremelycoolimage.com/image.png';`

   `img.classList.add("image-class");`

   `div.appendChild(img);`

I wish you luck in your project.

Edit: I believe what you're experiencing is adjusting the height and width of the CONTAINER but image elements are defaulted as an inline-block element. So, the width and height of the image (i think) are maintained when appended to the container regardless of the containers height / width definition.

Answer (score 1):

Try somthing like this:

```js
document.getElementById("myImg").height = "300";
document.getElementById("myImg").width = "300";
```

```html
 <img id="myImg" src="https://i.redd.it/31b2ii8hchi31.jpg" width="107" height="98">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const img = document.getElementById('image-div');
img.style.width = '100px';
img.style.height = '100px';
```

This is how you can change the height and width of an image.
Add an id to your  and get that id in your js